# Retrieve JSON and output to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, json, scripting

I'm currently retrieving this kind of JSON data from a PowerShell script:

```json
[{"Name":"grp_SIR_RW"},{"Name":"grp_SIR_R"},{"Name":"grp_SPIE_RW"},{"Name":"grp_GOR_R"}]
```

I need to retrieve each names in this output and paste them into HTML checkboxes so my users can select one or many of them and the display needs to be well organized since I can have like 30 groups to display.

Comment: *"paste them"* ??? wouldn't you rather write some code to extract them and create checkboxes?

Comment: Sure you can call it that way, I basically want to extract the group names and put them into the input's value

Comment: So, what have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use JavaScript to parse the JSON data and dynamically create HTML checkboxes for each group name. Here's a basic example of how you can do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Group Selection</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Select Groups</h2>

<div id="checkboxes-container">
  <!-- Checkboxes will be dynamically added here -->
</div>

<script>
  // JSON data retrieved from PowerShell script
  var jsonData = [{"Name":"grp_SIR_RW"},{"Name":"grp_SIR_R"},{"Name":"grp_SPIE_RW"},{"Name":"grp_GOR_R"}];

  // Get the container where checkboxes will be added
  var checkboxesContainer = document.getElementById("checkboxes-container");

  // Loop through the JSON data and create checkboxes
  jsonData.forEach(function(group) {
    // Create a checkbox element
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "group";
    checkbox.value = group.Name;
    
    // Create a label for the checkbox
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(group.Name));
    
    // Add checkbox and label to the container
    checkboxesContainer.appendChild(checkbox);
    checkboxesContainer.appendChild(label);
    checkboxesContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); // Add line break for spacing
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code dynamically creates checkboxes for each group name in the JSON data. Each checkbox is accompanied by a label displaying the group name. You can customize the appearance and layout further according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically create the checkbox from the json

```js
const data = [{
    "Name": "grp_SIR_RW"
  },
  {
    "Name": "grp_SIR_R"
  },
  {
    "Name": "grp_SPIE_RW"
  },
  {
    "Name": "grp_GOR_R"
  }
]
// creating a fragment to hold the dynamically created checkbox
// and it will be used to project the elements to the main 
//container
const temp = document.createElement('template')

data.forEach((item) => {
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', item.Name);
  label.textContent = item.Name;
  const check = document.createElement('input');
  check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
  check.id = item.Name;
  // appending the created elements to the fragment
  temp.content.appendChild(label);
  temp.content.appendChild(check);
});


const clone2 = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById('checkBoxContainer').appendChild(clone2)
```

```html
<div id="checkBoxContainer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking on how to display the JSON data in HTML which is already retrieved from the data source, in such case, try the following

In HTML create a place holder for check box

```
<div id="checkboxContainer">
    <!-- Place to create the checkboxes -->
</div>
```

next the data has to dynamically inserted into the HTML place holder, so try the following in JS, assuming that you have already retrieved the data.

```
const jsonData = [{ "Name": "grp_SIR_RW" }, { "Name": "grp_SIR_R" }, { "Name": "grp_SPIE_RW" }, { "Name": "grp_GOR_R" }];

const generateCheckboxes = async (data) => {
    var container = document.getElementById('checkboxContainer');

    data.forEach(function (item) {
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.name = 'group';
        checkbox.value = item.Name;

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.appendChild(checkbox);
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.Name));

        container.appendChild(label);
    });
}
```

Next this function has to be triggered, so assuming that you would be having a  function to fetch the data, once the data is fetched, call the function and pass the data to the function.

```
await generateCheckboxes(jsonData);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: why are you using `async`/`await` for this? that makes no sense at all

Comment: It is up to the user on how they would require it, if they need they can use it, it does not matter

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I asked WHY are you using async await for THIS code. What function does it serve?